# How to edit Bootstrap to use Slider Revolution short code in header

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal, revolution-slider

I am pretty new to css so I hope I am explaining properly. I am working in a theme that currently has a single banner image in the header..I need to change that out with a multiple image slider (slider revolution) - From what I understand I need to create custom code to edit the bootstrap file but I am not sure of what code I would add to delete the current single image banner and replace with the slider. The theme does not give this option or an option to add multiple images in the theme options.

Comment: Welcome to `SO` Please elaborate your question for others to understand.

Comment: Pretty sure you're looking for Bootstrap's Carousel: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel